# ASP.NET Web Application Productivity in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working on a fairly large ASP.NET web application and I'm taking a big productivity hit when I do work in the interface.  I can zip through adding features to the database and API, then I hit the interface and having to recompile and run eats up a lot of my day.

For example if i'm working on a tricky bit that isn't behaving quite right and requires a number of tweaks I'll have to go through multiple [stop/tweak/build/run/log in/navigate back to page] cycles, which really kills my flow and has me staring at the screen with my finger hovering over the hackernews bookmark each time.

I've been fiddling with ways to get around this problem but I haven't improved my situation much.  Here's what I've found so far:

- visual studio will restart the app frequently when you change static files (js/css/etc), which shouldn't require a restart.  If you run VS with IIS express instead this problem goes away.
- If I  know I have a bunch of messing around to do i'll cut/paste my code into a server script tag on the markup page, run the product, and tweak until it's good, then cut/paste it back.  This is annoying because it often requires setting up a number of Imports page declarations and code editing features in ASP.NET files, while better than ever in VS2010, is not as good as in C# files.  Plus, it still restarts the app occasionally once enough changes are made.
- I can exclude the codebehind file from the web application project, change the "codebehind" attribute in the aspx page declaration to an "src" attribute, then edit the code from there while the app runs (until i make enough changes to trigger a restart.)  However now intellisense doesn't work in the codebehind, among other things.

Am I missing something blindingly obvious here, or is development in ASP.NET web applications really supposed to be this slow?  Thanks for any solutions you can offer.

Comment: It does get a bit repetitive at times, what with the tweak, recompile, run, etc.  But for me this is quite trivial.  Maybe I've been working with it for too long that I just don't notice it much anymore.

Comment: The worst is when I finish up a bunch of work in my API/DB and then start working on the interface, I feel like I'm suddenly working in slow motion.

Comment: Allot of newer developers (that I've known) have always used the designer to build their UI - oddly, I've found that to be counter productive for me.  I type fast and much prefer to be under the hood at all times.  I suppose it also depends on your development machine...I've got enough juice in this machine that compiling and running is very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a combination of techniques that brings my productivity up a fair bit.

- Use an alternative browser like Chrome.  When you stop the VS debugger and you're using IE, VS will shut down the browser, but it won't do it with Chrome (or Firefox, or anything else.)
- Switched web.config to run in Windows Authentication mode and wrote a quick transparent login routine enclosed in conditional compilation tags (debug only, this feature is not perfect for our production product.)

Now when I'm getting into it I can stop the debugger (which no longer closes the browser,) make code changes, build, optionally start the debugger again, and just hit F5 in Chrome to load the latest.  The refresh obviously takes longer since the app has to start up but there's no "run browser/log in/navigate back to the page" task anymore.

Hopefully this will help somebody else in a similar situation.

Answer (score 2):

I never run my applications through Visual Studio.  Set yourself up with IIS and then configure a site to point to the location of your application along with a faux domain.  Edit your hosts file to point the domain to localhost.

Then when you want to view your site, just visit the domain that you chose.  If you need to modify CSS or script, just make your changes and refresh the page.  If you make a code change, compile your app and then refresh the page.

If you need to actually use the Visual Studio debugger, then just attach to the IIS process (application pool name) and your breakpoints will get hit.

Comment: Ek0nomik, this seems like a reasonable way to work, but making a codebehind change will still require all of the steps I was complaining about - build, wait for app to start up, log in, navigate to page, etc. except that changes to non-dynamic files won't trigger an app restart, but that's also solved by running IIS Express in VS.  Or am I missing the point?

Comment: You will have to compile the application and wait for the initial load; there's no way around that.  IIS will restart the application pool when you build, so those resources have to be loaded again.  You should *not* have to log in to your site again unless you're using some odd authentication.  When you log in you should be getting a cookie, and that cookie will stay valid beyond a new build of your site.

Comment: The only downside with this approach is that attaching to a process disables the Intellitrace functionality in the VS2010 Ultimate edition. Not an issue for all but worth pointing out.

Comment: Well it isn't that there's *no* way, for example cut/pasting codebehind code into a server-side script block as I described above allows you to make many code changes without having to build the project or restart the app.  It's just not terribly convenient.  From the lack of other responses here I'm guessing I'll have to just focus on reducing app startup time in debug mode somehow and doing a security bypass (our security system will kick users out when the app restarts, so that has to be taken care of.)  Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: `our security system will kick users out when the app restarts` - That sounds very fragile.  Your application will restart on its own if it's not getting much traffic, at least with the default IIS settings.  You could change the IIS settings to not restart after 30 minutes of inactivity, but it still sounds fragile to me.